# WSO2, XML to JSON, force a single element to be treated as array

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

In Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0 I'm converting a XML to JSON payload.

If the XML source has a single element it gets obviously treated as a single object

```
<items>
 <item></item>
</items>
```

becomes

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": {}
    }
}
```

but if there are more element, the specific object is treated as an array

```
<items>
 <item></item>
 <item></item>
</items>
```

becomes

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": [{}, {}]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to align the conversion of a specific sub-object? In this case, I'm trying to always return an item array, even when there is only a single element.

I read about the `xml-multiple` property but I couldn't understand how to use it; is it to be set manually to the source xml payload?

Comment: What is the EI version that you use

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: 6.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Json transform mediator[1] to achieve your use-case. Here we need to define the json schema to match the expected data structure. For the above case you will be able to use a json schema similar to the following.

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "item": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "object"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "item"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "items"
  ]
}
```

This specifies that the item is an array. Then the schema can be added to the registry [2] and referred in the json transform mediator. The Json transform mediator needs to be added after the xml to json transformation. Refer to the following sample proxy service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="transform"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
         <jsontransform schema="conf:/schema.json"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

input 1

```
<items>
 <item><val1></val1></item>
 <item><val1></val1></item>
</items>
```

output 1

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": [
            {
                "val1": null
            },
            {
                "val1": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

input 2

```
<items>
 <item><val1></val1></item>
</items>
```

output 2

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": [
            {
                "val1": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/JSON+Transform+Mediator

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Managing+the+Registry+

Comment: Interesting solution. How to make this work with input like `<items><item>MaValue</item>
</items>` ??

Comment: If you are only expecting a string value instead of a object, then in the Json schema, you can modify the     "items": [
            {
              "type": "object"
            }
          ]        ===>          "items": [
            {
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]

Comment: but if it is possible to get a object or a string, both data types need to be defined in the Json schema

Comment: Really, really thanks for you answer. Sadly I think I'll go this way, even if it's a slower solution than what I hoped...

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `filterMediator` and `enrichMediator` like below. If there is not a second item:

1. Store the `<item>` element for example as `ONE_ITEM`,
2. Build `<items>` node with `<?xml-multiple item?>`,
3. Enrich that new `<items>` object with stored `ONE_ITEM`.

I don't know better option for injecting the `<?xml-multiple item?>` XML processing instruction.
Something like below works for me.

```
      <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="not(//item[2])">
        <then>
          <enrich>
            <source clone="false" xpath="//item"/>
            <target type="property" property="ONE_ITEM"/>
          </enrich>
          <enrich>
            <source type="inline" clone="false">
              <items xmlns="">
                <?xml-multiple item?>
              </items>
            </source>
            <target xpath="//items"/>
          </enrich>
          <enrich>
            <source type="property" clone="false" property="ONE_ITEM"/>
            <target action="child" xpath="//items"/>
          </enrich>
        </then>
        <else/>
      </filter>
      <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with XSLT transformation by adding `<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">item</xsl:processing-instruction>` to your message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<items xmlns="">
    <item>
        <REQUEST_STATUS>SUCCESSFUL</REQUEST_STATUS>
    </item>
</items>
```

If the  element contains only a single <REQUEST_STATUS> child element. Despite having a single child element, WSO2 interprets "item" as an object (not an array) in the JSON output. The resulting JSON structure represents "item" as an object with a single "REQUEST_STATUS" value

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": {
            "REQUEST_STATUS": "SUCCESSFUL"
        }
    }
}
```

The inclusion of the  processing instruction marks the  element as a container for multiple occurrences, even when only one occurrence is present. As a result, WSO2 EI interprets "item" as an array, ensuring consistency in the JSON output structure. In this case, the JSON output depicts "item" as an array containing a single object with the "REQUEST_STATUS" value.

```
<items xmlns="">
    <item>
        <?xml-multiple item?>
        <REQUEST_STATUS>SUCCESSFUL</REQUEST_STATUS>
    </item>
</items>
```

Output:

```
{
    "items": {
        "item": [
            {
                "REQUEST_STATUS": "SUCCESSFUL"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Example**
Input:

```
<jsonObject xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <?xml-multiple jsonObject?>
    <jsonObject xmlns="">
        <REQUEST_STATUS>SUCCESSFUL</REQUEST_STATUS>
    </jsonObject>
</jsonObject>
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "REQUEST_STATUS": "SUCCESSFUL"
    }
]
```