# WSO2 EI 6.6.0, JSONTransformMediator "Invalid JSON schema" / "JSON schema is false, so all validations will fail"

Tags: wso2, jsonschema, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm validating a JSON received from a dataservice through a JSON Schema.

```
 {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "funzioni": {
      "type": ["null","object"],
      "properties": {
        "funzioniUO": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [{
              "type": "object"
           }]
        }
      }
    },
    "countDipendenti": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "countQualifiche": {
          "type": ["null","object"],
          "properties": {
            "countPerQualifica": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": [{
                  "type": "object"
               }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With Integration Studio's Micro Integrator the validation happens without errors, but with EI 6.6.0 I get the following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-08-27 15:10:07,586] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.JSONTransformMediator} - Invalid JSON schema org.apache.synapse.commons.json.jsonprocessor.exceptions.ValidatorException: Invalid JSON schema
```

I tried adding the $schema and $id meta fields, without success.

Another error I'm having with another, simpler schema is

```
 {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "result": {
      "type": ["null","object"],
      "properties": {
        "uos": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [{
              "type": "object"
           }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-08-27 15:12:47,032] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.JSONTransformMediator} - JSON schema is false, so all validations will fail org.apache.synapse.commons.json.jsonprocessor.exceptions.ValidatorException: JSON schema is false, so all validations will fail
```

I tried googling the errors, but without any success

What is not valid on my schemas, or why only EI thinks they are not?

Comment: Do you still get the same error if your schema is `true`? I ask, because it sounds like your schema is being coercedc to `false` somehow. Given this problem is with specific tooling, it might be worth creating an issue with the vendor?

Comment: I don't even know what would a "true" or "false" schema mean

Comment: Booleans are valid JSON Schema. The values of the `properties` objects are JSON Schema, as is the value of `items`, so you could do `"items": false` . You often see `additionalProperties: false`, but the value is actually a JSON Schema.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation. What should I change to the schema to make it "true" and test your request?

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending that `"items": [{ ... }]` will apply that subschema just the first item in your array, or all items?

If you want it to apply to all items, then change to `"items": { ... }`.

If you want to apply just to the first item, check to see what specification version your validator is using -- the syntax is fine for draft2019-09 and earlier, but in draft2020-12, the keyword for this type of validation changed to "prefixItems".

Comment: The schema has that field because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939737/wso2-xml-to-json-force-a-single-element-to-be-treated-as-array (I wanted an "properties", "funzioniUO" and "countPerQualifica" to be always treated as array during a xml -> json conversion).
EI 6.6.0 was released on 2019 anyway...